# Created ViewModel for EntityFramework Drop Down List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to have a drop down that won't require to to query the database in the controller POST section in order to get the ID for the drop down selection so that it can be placed in table as a foreign key. I don't understand how it could be down without needing to make that query. I want entity framework to do the heavy lifting for it if that makes sense? Is this possible?

```
public class BillRate
   {
        public BillRate()
        {
            this.BillRateTickets = new List<Ticket>();
        }

        public long BillRateID { get; set; }
        public decimal TicketBillRate { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Ticket> BillRateTickets { get; set; }
    }

public class Ticket
    {


        public long TicketID { get; set; }

        public virtual BillRate BillRate { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: sorry but out of your description i can't unterstand what you want to do.. rework you description and show more details if you want help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what exactly do you mean. If you do not query your database where where do you think the items to be displayed on the dropdown list will come from? They will definetely won't come from the view because in HTML when you submit a form containing a `<select>` element, only the selected value is ever sent to the server. The collection values are never sent, so ASP.NET MVC cannot invent those values for you.

If you want to avoid hitting your database you could store this list into the cache and inside your POST action try looking for the values in the cache first. But those values must be persisted somewhere on your server. So you could have a method which will look for the values in the cache first and if not found query the database:

```
private IEnumerable<Ticket> GetTickets()
{
    // Try to get the tickets from the cache first:
    var tickets = MemoryCache.Default["tickets"] as IEnumerable<Ticket>;
    if (tickets == null)
    {
        // not found in cache, let's fetch them from the database:
        tickets = db.Tickets.ToList();
        // and now store them into the cache so that next time they will be available
        MemoryCache.Default.Add("tickets", tickets, new CacheItemPolicy { Priority = CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable });
    }

    return tickets;
}
```

and then you could have the 2 controller actions:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new BillRate();
    model.BillRateTickets = GetTickets();
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(BillRate model)
{
    model.BillRateTickets = GetTickets();
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: I only want to avoid querying to match BillRateID to the BillRate selection in the drop down. I want that to already be queried waiting for me. I was hoping it could be tied to the list somehow to make it simple. But that makes sense if you can't.